# What material is this countertop?

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops

I have heard conflicting a assessments that this material is marble and granite. It has some etching from citrus acid as well as a square pattern on the underside of the counter[image]

[image]

Edit: below is a picture ID what I am calling etching. Please correct me if I’m mistaken.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may also be a composite material of some time, sometimes called *cultured marble*. This has the advantages of a soft stone material - i.e., it won't be as hard as granite but is not a thin laminate. I suspect something of this sort because of the square pattern. A square pattern can easily come from a mold, but would be, I think, relatively unusual to be cut into actual stone.

An advantage of a composite material is that it can be shaped into almost any form. A typical example is a counter with an integrated sink.

Comment: "Quartz is a much harder material. The Mohs scale hardness of marble is roughly 3, whereas that of quartz is around 7. This makes it much more resistant to scratching, however it also makes re-polishing and general processing a more difficult task, which is why it is most commonly used for kitchen counter tops, where the value added through processing can offset its considerably higher cost." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineered_stone - Granite (8) does not scratch like that, nor does it readily etch. Even if it was, the remedy is to polish it. And then be nicer to your fake marble floor.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely marble, as opposed to granite.

Both the visual appearance and the [acid etching](https://youtu.be/_cZm4PvGPzE?si=1__MKnThaQXCCI8a) support that, and the acid etching also rules out plastic-imitation-marble which would be visually similar.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can tell this way.  Its not clear if what you call etching is etching,  Both are porous and will absorb liquids.  When we had granite benchtop in the kitchen, we were warned to clear up acidic spells right away.

If its important, you can call a professional.  There are also testing kits,  Here's the first one I came across.

> ***MB Stone Professional's Stone ID Kit™ Wins Best of Innovation at TISE in 2023!***
>
> We get questions all the time about how to ID a particular stone and it seems to be a challenge across the board for old and new. As new types of stones are being introduced into the market all the time, it has become even more difficult. We have partnered with geologist Karin Kirk to put together a kit designed to help our stone pros identify any type of stone they may come across when out on a job.
>
> We are positive that you will find this kit to be an asset. This stone identification kit comes packed in a case of it's own with all the tools you will need to identify your stone.
>
> The kit includes:
>
> Mohs' Hardness Test Kit with Mohs scale and instructions
> 1oz of HCL 10% solution in an easy to use squeeze bottle
> A magnifying glass
> A 1x4 glass tile
> 10 razor blades w/case
> Stone ID flow chart and instructions, created by Karin Kirk
> HCL 10% solution has a shelf life of 3-5 years and should be stored in a cool, dry area.

Comment: Just linked this in WRT acid and granite: https://youtu.be/_cZm4PvGPzE?si=1__MKnThaQXCCI8a Granite can stain, but it doesn't etch.

Comment: I’ve updated my original post with an image of what I’m calling etching.